# migrating htaccess from localhost WAMP to godaddy subdomain

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, subdomain

First off this is similar to other stack questions however none of the solutions helped me. so before your mark as duplicate, or whine about the question try look for solutions and not problems with the question.

Hi all, here's the scoop, I have tried to be thorough.

I have a site that is in mid development.
A potential employer wants to check out the site in its current state.
In order to do this I had to put it as a sub domain of a site I already have hosted with GoDaddy.

the site uses pretty urls that link to php scripts in various directories.

**mysite.com/location**

would, via htaccess rules go to a script at

**mysite.com/src/script/php/location/location.php**

or another example might be

****mysite.com/location/fj83jfd83****

would, via htaccess rules go to a script at

**mysite.com/src/script/php/location/location.php?item=fj83jfd83**

my htaccess file works on my local WAMP stack but not once on the remote goddady server hosted with linux cpanel
my htaccess file is as follows

```
RewriteEngine On 
    RewriteBase /
    AddDefaultCharset utf-8 
    RewriteRule ^location/([A-Za-z0-9]+)/?$ src/script/php/location/location.php?item=$1 [NC,L]
    RewriteRule ^location$ src/script/php/location/location.php [NC,L]
```

---

**Question one**

I am wondering what changes do I need to make to the htaccess file for this to  work on the GoDaddy server on a subdomain like **mysite.hostedsite.com**?

---

**Question 2**

would the htaccess go in the base public root folder or the subdomain root folder?

---

Couple things to note. 
I am open to options that don't use htaccess or another work around that hasn't occurred to me.
This is only for someone to view the site, so a short term patch(hack) solution is fine, the site is not ready for launch.
thanks you in advance

Answer (score 0):

All I needed to do was add the subdomain to the start of the rewrite rule.

so

**RewriteRule ^location$ src/script/php/location/location.php [NC,L]**

needed to be

**RewriteRule ^mysite/location$ src/script/php/location/location.php [NC,L]**

just left it encase it helps any one in the future!